# how do I output the rowName based on a linking table?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need to output A_Name, B_Name, and C_Name. from tableA, tableB, tableC. I have a linking table containing all the ID's of the above, e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableLink` (
   `tableLinkID` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `A_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `B_ID` int(5) NOT NULL,
   `C_ID` int(5) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`tableLinkID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

My question: I need to know how to SELECT based on having **C_ID**, how to select and output A_ID's [A_Name], B_ID's [B_Name], and C_ID's [C_Name].

I hope this is clear enough.

(I have the **C_ID** in a variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JOINs:

```
SELECT
    tableA.A_Name,
    tableB.B_Name,
    tableC.C_Name
FROM tableLink
JOIN tableA ON tableLink.A_ID = A.ID
JOIN tableB ON tableLink.B_ID = B.ID
JOIN tableC ON tableLink.C_ID = C.ID
WHERE tableLink.C_ID = 42
```

Comment: Damn, I just realised my A_ID is not in the tableLink, it's only in tableA and tableB (Clients has-> Projects).

Comment: I've added A_ID to my tableLink. Is the tableA.A_Name trying to select from tableLink?