# SQL JOIN help. Outputting table.rowName * 3 based on a Linking table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a linking table with all the ID's of the tables linked.

My JOIN isn't working, though :

```
       $strSql="SELECT clients.clientName,
           projects.projectName,
           projectTemplates.projectTempName
    FROM   projectTempList
    JOIN   clients ON projectTempList.clientID = clients.clientID
    JOIN   projects ON projectTempList.projectID = projects.projectID
    JOIN   projectTemplates ON projectTempList.projectTemplateID = projectTemplates.projectTempID
    WHERE  projectTempList.projectCostID = $intProjectCostId";
```

Structure in my linking table is:

```
 projectTempList ->    projectID, clientID, projectTemplateID, projectCostID
```

I need to select the `clientName`, `projectName`, `projectTempName` from **`clients`**, **`projects`**, and **`projectTemplates`**. This is based on having a linked table with the respective ID's in a table called **`projectTempList`**.

I have the **costID** in a variable.

**EDIT**`JOIN   clients ON projectTempList.clientID = clients.clientID` needed to be clients.projectclientID.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it the same question as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515624/how-do-i-output-the-rowname-based-on-a-linking-table ?

Comment: @tsabz: That's a stretch.  The problem is probably related to OP's specific data model and contents of the tables.

Comment: No, my question is why my JOIN isn't working.

Comment: Try to echo your $strSql and test it directly in MySQL, and see what error you get.

Comment: I'm returning 0 in my while loop and getting my no data echo. i.e $objResult=mysql_query($strSQL) if(mysql_num_rows($objResult)==0) echo "no data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- Output `echo $strSql;` and see if it is what you expect. Test it against MySQL directly (i.e. PHPMyAdmin)
- Ensure you are not returning any errors with `echo mysql_error();`
- You mentioned having `clientID`, but your `WHERE` clause uses `projectCostID`
- Be mindful of [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), i.e. properly escape `$intProjectCostId` with something like `" . (int)$intProjectCostId`

Comment: Ok awesome. Will do. I meant CostID. oops.